# Android camera preview with color filter

Tags: java, android, colors, filter, camera

I have a `CameraPreview` class. It extends `SurfaceView` and implements `SurfaceHolder.Callback` and `PreviewCallback`. I would like to change image, which camera sends to `SurfaceView`. It should be done in the following part of the code:

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame");
    Canvas canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();
    synchronized (mHolder) {
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 200, p);
        mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }   
}
```

But I get following exception:

`Exception locking surface
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
            at android.view.Surface.nativeLockCanvas(Native Method)
            at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:243)`

Google says that the error occures because of the unlocked canvas, but i always leave it locked.
How can I draw over the image on `SurfaceView`?

I create a function which apply color filter with exist image, i hope this code is correct.

```
@Override
protected void overDraw(Canvas canvas) {        
    Paint p = new Paint();
    ColorMatrixColorFilter fl = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new ColorMatrix(filter));
    p.setColorFilter(fl);
    canvas.drawPaint(p);
    Log.d(TAG, "overDraw");
}

float[] filter = new float[]
{ 
    //r, g, b, a, k
    0.33,0.33,0.33,0,0, //r
    0.33,0.33,0.33,0,0, //g
    0.33,0.33,0.33,0,0, //b
    0,0,0,1,0,  //a
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot change the SurfaceView camera preview. The `onPreviewFrame()` callback happens independently from drawing the camera preview on the surface. You can overlay the surface with another view, which could mask it. If your manipulation is simple, you can use a TextureView instead and apply some OpenGL shader on the texture received from camera. But usually we simply hide the live preview and push the **data** received in `onPreviewFrame()` after manipulation.